# Obtain CRS compliant WKT from GeoPackage with ogrinfo

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr, geopackage, well-known-text

I would like to obtain the WKT for a few geometries stored in a GeoPackage file with `orginfo`. That is the function of the `-al` parameter. However, when applied directly to the file in question it creates WKT strings with swapped coordinate axes. A small example:

```
$ ogrinfo point.gpkg -al
INFO: Open of `point.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: point
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-150.000000, 1.000000) - (-150.000000, 1.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
FID Column = fid
Geometry Column = geom
lat: Integer (0.0)
lon: Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(point):1
  lat (Integer) = 1
  lon (Integer) = -150
  POINT (-150 1)
```

Even though `ogrinfo` correctly reports axes order and SRS domain in the SRS WKT field, in the very last line the geometry stored in this file is reported with swapped axes.

Is there a way to obtain the correct WKT from a GeoPackage with `ogrinfo`?

Comment: GDAL considers that WKT is always longitude-latitude or easting-northing. PostGIS  behaves in the same way. I know that some other programs are axis order aware with WKT (at least MySQL). When you use GDAL interpret also `Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1`. In the native GeoPackage BLOB the coordinates are also always stored in longitude-latitude/easting northing order.

Comment: I would say that does not square with the [OGR 06-103r4 specification](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355), that states: "The interpretation of the coordinates is subject to the coordinate reference systems associated to the point". The EPSG specification for the WGS84 is very clear regarding axes order. I am currently unable to import geometries in WKT format to other programmes because of this issue.

Comment: Yes, it may be wrong but GDAL and so many other programs interpreted that standard (and WMS 1.1.x and WFS 1.x standards) for so many years in the longitude-latitude/easting northing way that changing the interpretation would make at least as much trouble. MySQL did the change but also implemented an option to support the other axis order https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html. Make your program to accept both variants because both exists in the wild. I suppose that with Python it is possible to make GDAL to write lat-lon WKT but I doubt that ogrinfo will ever do that.

Comment: See the line data axis to crs axis mapping 2,1 which explains the relationship

Comment: What are the other programs that you refer to? Maybe we can find a workaround.

Comment: The plain WKT `POINT (-150 1)` does not tell anything about CRS but the software must get that information from some supporting source. What if you tell your program that the CRS of the WKT geometry is CRS:84 http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84?

Comment: @user30184 The plain WKT geometry comes right after the WKT of the CRS, I would expect them to match. The GeoSPARQL standard explicitly requires WKT literals to comply with the axes order defined by the CRS. Therefore this is a problem with any triple store or other programme supporting GeoSPARQL. The workaround with CRS:84 is worth a try (will report back). But the best would be if OGR could simply follow the standards. Axes order is a feature of CRS definition and beyond GeoSPARQL, also explicitly required in GML. PROJ in its turn supports axes order quite well.

Comment: So you are forwarding also the CRS WKT to GeoSPARQL? Ogrinfo is a general purpose info tool that is written mostly for human users and not so much to be used as a part of a ETL process.  But with little effort you could make a script that takes into account also the "Data axis to CRS axis mapping" line. Or make a script that writes out GML. Or tell GeoSPARQL to use the default of the standard. `"Point(-83.38  33.95)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>`.

Comment: @user30184 I successfully tested the workaround you proposed. Also, going through the OGC 11-052r4 specification, I verified that in fact CRS:84 is assumed by default in case no CRS URI is provided. However, I still think `ogrinfo` should be more precise in the way it reports geometries. It could for instance provide an option to enforce CRS compliant axes order.

Comment: And I still think that with "Data axis to CRS axis mapping" ogrinfo is precise and changing what it does would make more confusion than good. I understand that you will keep your position and consider that PostGIS etc. should make the same move. But perhaps WKT itself should be made explicit and include also the CRS definition and WKT version number. Now there is no way to know if some published WKT is created when https://gismanual.com/relational/99-049_OpenGIS_Simple_Features_Specification_For_SQL_Rev_1.1.pdf was the official standard. That version defined only "x" and "y".